# How to insert multiple row at a time in SQLite in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my SQLite database only one row effect but I want effect 4 rows at a time. My code is working for one row, not for other value save. How to write the code for saving multiple rows in SQLite?

I create application for weather. I get all weather condition information by XML parsing, I parse all value in table view I see all value. This is all proper.

In XML file I get current condition element and three forecast condition it mean current condition it show today weather condition and forecast condition show next 3 days of weather conditions. I create for fetch this data .3class with name currentcondition and forecastcondition.

In forecastcondition element I have same name of next 3day element name means element name same forecastcondition I store all forecast condition value in array for take value one by one of next 3day value show it working proper in table cell. I see current condition value on 1cell and all next 3forecastcondition display in next 3cell my code is proper working but now I want store first cell value and next 3day value cell in sqlite database table at a time but how can I store?

But I save currentcondition in SQLite because I create object of currentcondition class then I pass value to SQLite. So how to parse another cell value at same time? My table is one and which I give all column name in attach file; I want insert value in this table column only.

I write this code for store SQLite please check the code. This my controller class where I display value on cell here only I wrirten code for SQLite for save data.

```
    //
    //  TWeatherController.m
    //  Journey
    //
    //  Created by pradeep.yadav on 5/3/11.
    //  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "TWeatherController.h"
    #import "TWeatherCell.h"
    #import "ForecastInfoParser.h"
    #import "global.h"
    #define DATABASE_NAME @"test.sqlite"
    #define DATABASE_TITLE @"test"
    #import <sqlite3.h>



    @implementation TWeatherController
    @synthesize MyTableView;
    @synthesize forecastcond;

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark View lifecycle







    - (NSString *) getWritableDBPath {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
    }

    -(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded 
    {
        // Testing for existence
        BOOL success;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
        NSLog(@"%@",writableDBPath);

        success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
        if (success)
            return;

        // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to
        // the appropriate location.
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath
                                       toPath:writableDBPath
                                        error:&error];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with Message : '%@'.",
                      [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }


    -(BOOL) insertData

    { 
     [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
     //NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];
        BOOL value = NO; 

        @try { 

            sqlite3 *database; 
            if (sqlite3_open([[self getWritableDBPath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
            { 
                sqlite3_close(database); 
            } 
            else { 
                NSString *nsQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO weather (ReportDate,conditionname,humidity,maxtemp,mintemp,wind) VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')" ,_forecastInfo.CurrentDateTime,currentcond.Condition,currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.WindCondition,currentcond.Humidity]; 
                const char *query = [nsQuery UTF8String]; 
                [nsQuery release]; 

                sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
                int errorCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, NULL); 
                if(errorCode == SQLITE_OK) { 
                    int result = sqlite3_step(statement); 
                    if(result == SQLITE_DONE) { 
                        value = YES; 
                        sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
                    } 
                } 
                sqlite3_close(database); 
            } 
        } 
        @catch (NSException *exception) { 
            NSLog(@"Error encountered while reading facts: %@", [exception reason]); 
        } 
        return value; 
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _forecastInfo=nil;
        currentcond=nil;
        forecastcond=nil;
        NSString *URL=@"http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=,,,50500000,30500000"; 
        NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]; 
        NSURLResponse *resp = nil; 
        NSError *err = nil; 
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
        NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        //[resp release]; 
        [err release]; 
        NSLog(@"response: %@", theString);    
        ForecastInfoParser *parser=[[ForecastInfoParser alloc]init];
        parser.delegate=self;
        [parser parseData:response];


        //[self selected];
        [self insertData];


    }


    -(void)forecastInfoParser:(ForecastInfoParser*)parser parsed:(ForecastInformation*)forecastInfo 
    {
        _forecastInfo=[forecastInfo retain];
        [MyTableView reloadData];
    }

    -(void)forecastInfo:(ForecastInfoParser*)parser parsed:(CurrentCondition*)currentcondition
    {
        currentcond=[currentcondition retain];
        [MyTableView reloadData];
    }

    -(void)forecastInfoCondition:(ForecastInfoParser*)parser parsed:(NSMutableArray *)forecastcondition
    {
        forecastcond=[forecastcondition retain];
        [MyTableView reloadData];
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if(_forecastInfo&&currentcond&&forecastcond)
            return 4;
        return 0;

    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        TWeatherCell *cell =(TWeatherCell *) [MyTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]];
        if (cell == nil) {
            //cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell = [[[TWeatherCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%d", indexPath.row]] autorelease];
        }
        //ForecastCondition *cond=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:0];
        cond1=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:1];
        cond2=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:2];
        cond3=[forecastcond objectAtIndex:3];
        if ([currentcond.Icon isEqualToString:@"http://\n"])
        {
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
        }
        else {
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentcond.Icon]];       
            NSLog(@"this is image from server:%@",imageData);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [imageData release];
        }
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *date_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
        NSString *str=NSLocalizedString(@"date",nil);
        [date_formatter setDateFormat:str]; 
        NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
        //NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *thursday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:secondsPerDay sinceDate:today];
        NSDate *friday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:2*secondsPerDay sinceDate:today];
        NSDate *sunday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:3*secondsPerDay sinceDate:today];
        //tomorrow = [today addTimeInterval:secondsPerDay];
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
                NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentcond.Icon]];
                NSLog(@"this is image from server:%@",imageData);
                cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
                [imageData release];
            file://localhost/Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/JourneyMapper/Journey/Classes/TJourneyTabBar.hcell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];     
                cell.reportdate.text = _forecastInfo.CurrentDateTime;
                //cell.conditionname.text = currentcond.Condition;
                [cell setConditionName:currentcond.Condition];      
                //[cell setConditionName:cond1.Condition];
                cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Tempc];
                cell.twodirection.text = currentcond.WindCondition;
                cell.humidity.text = currentcond.Humidity;

                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
                cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo]; 
                cell.reportdate.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thursday];
                //cell.conditionname.text = cond1.Condition;
                [cell setConditionName:cond1.Condition];
                cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond1.Low,cond1.High];
                break;
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
                cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
                cell.reportdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",friday];
                //cell.conditionname.text = cond2.Condition;
                [cell setConditionName:cond2.Condition];
                cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond2.Low,cond2.High];
                break;
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
                cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
                cell.reportdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sunday];
                //cell.conditionname.text = cond3.Condition;
                [cell setConditionName:cond3.Condition];
                cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond3.Low,cond3.High];
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Out of Range ",indexPath.row);
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }






    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
        /*
         <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
         // ...
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
         [detailViewController release];
         */
    }



    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
    {
        return 100.0;
    }


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Memory management

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
        // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


    - (void)dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
        [_forecastInfo release];
        [currentcond release];
        [forecastConditions release];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what your asking is "how can I update 4 rows in one SQL command?"

The easiest way to do this is to use ";" to break up the sql statement to form 4 different queries executed in one string

Your main SQL string appears to be in the NSString nsQuery, here is a way you could set it although its a little tedious

```
NSString *qry1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO weather (ReportDate,conditionname,humidity,maxtemp,mintemp,wind) VALUES('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')" ,_forecastInfo.CurrentDateTime,currentcond.Condition,currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Wind2ondition,currentcond.Humidity]; 
NSString *qry2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO newtable(DifferentColumn) VALUES('Dummy Data')"]; 
NSString *qry3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO thirdtable(Temp) VALUES(3)"]; 
NSString *qry4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO forthtable(Other) VALUES('indigo')"]; 

NSString *nsQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@;%@;%@;%@",qry1,qry2,qry3,qry4];
```

Comment: i have to insert in same column and same table name also i dont want insert different diffrent column

Comment: @AlanMacGredor i want to insert value in same table and in there column name